# PHP import multiple rows in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with importing multiple data into database with Laravel.
I have request that looks like (Postman bulk edit form):

```
country_id[]:1
real_price[]:14.00
sale_price[]:23.23
country_id[]:68
real_price[]:198.23
sale_price[]:
country_id[]:179
real_price[]:956.23
sale_price[]:167.23
```

As you see user can add those 3 inputs as much as he wants, and I would need to import all of them at once.
Now database have product_id, country_id, real_price and sale_price, except that product_id is always the same.
I tried to make them as an array, like so:

```
$product_id = 1; // This is always same value!    
$data = array(
        'country_id' => $request->country_id,
        'real_price' => $request->real_price,
        'sale_price' => $request->sale_price
    );
```

But I have no idea how to foreach them and get that data. When I var_dump this $data variable I get this:

```
 array(3) {
["country_id"]=>
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(1) "1"
[1]=>
string(2) "68"
[2]=>
string(3) "179"
[3]=>
string(1) "1"
}
["real_price"]=>
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(5) "14.00"
[1]=>
string(6) "198.23"
[2]=>
string(6) "956.23"
[3]=>
string(1) "1"
}
["sale_price"]=>
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(5) "23.23"
[1]=>
NULL
[2]=>
string(6) "167.23"
[3]=>
string(1) "1"
}
}
```

Now the problem is how to import them into database.
I tried to foreach them like so:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            print_r($value[0]);
        }
```

And it will return me all values with value 0 like:

```
114.0023.23
```

But how to get the key? Every time says that for example country_id is undefined index.

I would need to import some how like this:

```
Prices::create(['product_id' => $product_id, $data ])
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how input is sent.
Try and send the input like this:

```
items[1][country_id]:1
items[1][real_price]:14.00
items[1][sale_price]:23.23
items[2][country_id]:68
items[2][real_price]:198.23
items[2][sale_price]:
items[3][country_id]:179
items[3][real_price]:956.23
items[3][sale_price]:167.23
```

This will create associative array that looks like this:

```
items: [
    0 => [
        'country_id' => 1,
        'real_price' => 14.00,
        'sale_price' => 23.23
    ],
    ...
]
```

Then in the controller you should be able to do something like this:

```
collect($request->input('items'))->each(function($item, $id) {
    $model = new Price();
    $model->fill($item)->save();
});
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If the data structure will always be as in your example, you can try to solve the problem like this

```
    use \Illuminate\Support\Arr;
    ...

    $data = Arr::only(request()->all(), ['country_id', 'real_price', 'sale_price']);
    $count = count(array_values($data)[0]);

    $pricesData = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        foreach($data as $key => $row) {
           $pricesData[$i][$key] = $data[$key][$i];
        }
        $pricesData[$i]['product_id'] = 1;
    }
    
    // dd($pricesData);

    Prices::createMany($pricesData);
```